# Only show first letters of string of each word

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have this string

```
Rock Paper Shotgun
```

I have looked around to find an easy way to get the first letters of each word. Because I want my end result to be:

```
RPS
```

Is there a special ruby on rails function for this? If not, how can I achieve such thing?

I found this

```
str = "nishant nigam"
=> "nishant nigam"
str.split(" ").map {|name| name[0].chr }.join.upcase
=> "NN"
```

But I was hoping if there is even a simpler method

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
"Rock Paper Shotgun".split.map(&:first).join.upcase
```

edit:

irb:
[4] pry(main)> "rock Paper Shotgun".split.map(&:first).join.upcase

=> "RPS"

Comment: Although, this solution will give you small letters as well if string is "Rock paper Shotgun" and will not give exactly what you would need

Comment: @Sharpless512 please mark the answer as correct if it helped you :)

Comment: Done :) Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Do it like this:

```
"Rock Paper Shotgun".split.map{|i| i[0,1].upcase}.join
```